# How much space needed to run Bitcoin daemon in amazon AMI?

Tags: bitcoind, litecoin, ubuntu, storage-footprint, amazon-web-services

How much space needed to run Bitcoin daemon in amazon AMI(ubuntu 12.04), I am currently having 20GB is that enough suppose i want to run multiple coin daemon say 6 coin daemons how much space(approx) i needed?

Comment: These clients also need a substantial amount of memory, which may be another consideration.

Answer (score 1):

The relevant space used is the one needed to store the blockchain, the public registry where all the bitcoin transaction are recorded. It's currently about 16GB, you can have a look of the growing rate here https://blockchain.info/charts/blocks-size